# Is the reciprocal of an even/odd function still going to remain even/odd?

Tags: functions

For instance the reciprocal of sin(x) seems to remain an odd function as well as all the other trigonometric functions. Would the be the case for all functions? If so how would you prove so?

Comment: Yes, assuming that you deal with the zeroes appropriately.  Check by applying the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They will retain their parity, ie.

$$f(-x) = -f(x) \implies \frac 1 {f(-x)} = \frac 1 {-f(x)} = - \frac 1 {f(x)}$$
$$f(-x) = f(x) \implies \frac 1 {f(-x)} = \frac 1 {f(x)}$$

Just make sure to account for zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

For even function,
$$f(x)=f(-x)$$
Let, 
$$g(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$$
$$g(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}=\frac{1}{f(-x)}=g(-x)$$
Similarly we can prove for odd functions

> for $z$ such that $f(z)=0$
>   It is also true that $f(-z)=0$$$$$
>   So $g(z)=g(-z)=\text{not defined}$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ is odd, where $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.  By definition of an odd function, we have $f(-x) = -f(x)$ for all $x\in X$.  Next, note that
$$ \frac{1}{f} : X\setminus\{x:f(x)=0\} \to \mathbb{R} $$
is defined by
$$ \frac{1}{f}(x) = \frac{1}{f(x)}. $$
We want to show that $\frac{1}{f}(-x) = -\frac{1}{f}(x)$ for all $x$ in the domain of $\frac{1}{f}$, i.e. all $x\in X$ such that $f(x) \ne 0$.  So, suppose that $x\in X\setminus\{x:f(x)=0\}$.  Then we have
$$
\frac{1}{f}(-x)
= \frac{1}{f(-x)}
= \frac{1}{-f(x)}
= -\frac{1}{f(x)}
= -\frac{1}{f}(x).
$$
Thus the reciprocal of an odd function is odd.

The proof is essentially the same for even functions.